# Can't mount an image created by ddrescue

Tags: ddrescue

I have a 500GB disk that I'm trying to recover using `GNU ddrescue`.

This is the `fdisk` for the 500GB disk:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xeea5da13

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63   976768064   488384001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

`ddrescue` completed its copying run and was doing this:

```
GNU ddrescue 1.21
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Initial status (read from mapfile)
  rescued:  481966 MB,     errsize:   70382 kB,  errors:     121

Current status
     ipos:  482180 MB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:    262 kB/s
     opos:  482180 MB, non-scraped:   17927 MB,  average rate:    614 kB/s
non-tried:        0 B,     errsize:   70382 kB,      run time:      3m 54s
  rescued:  482110 MB,      errors:      121,  remaining time:  1d 10h 58m
percent rescued:  96.40%      time since last successful read:          0s
Scraping failed blocks... (forwards)
```

The step above is now complete, and this is what `fdisk -l` says on the `backup.img` file:

```
Disk /media/victor/New Volume4/backup.img: 497.3 GB, 497334280192 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60464 cylinders, total 971356016 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xeea5da13

                               Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/media/victor/New Volume4/backup.img1              63   976768064   488384001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

When I do `sudo mount -o ro,offset=$((512*63)) backup.img /media/myName/recovery` I get:

```
Failed to read last sector (976768001): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/loop0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

What do I do now?

Comment: You've got the file as `backup.iso` and you're mounting `backup.img`... have I missed something?

Comment: Oh, sorry, typo.

Comment: `losetup -P` for partitioned disk image

Answer (score 1):

Wrong tool I suspect. `Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)?` is a useful pointer - My guess is you imaged /dev/sdc, and mount gets confused with device images.

Use kpartx instead - I believe kpartx -a -v  backup.img  will add a series of devices in /dev/mapper, which you can then mount as per normal.

Comment: Hmm... I get `device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p1 failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop0p1
add map loop0p1 (0:0): 0 976768002 linear /dev/loop0 63
`

Comment: hm. Seems similar to this https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=780142 what was wrong with the disk to start with?

Comment: It was just a 500GB HDD that I used to back up stuff to. NTFS file system. It started to read and write REALLY slow so I decided to image it and try to recover files from the image.

Comment: Bah, nevermind. I just mounted the image in Windows using 'OSFMount' and it works fine. Pulling files off of it now.

Comment: Post that as an answer I guess? I suppose I was right about 'wrong tool' but I have no idea where things went pear shaped.

Comment: Probably ddrescue didn't manage to copy the last couple of sectors, so the last part isn't readable as the image file is shorter. Linux tries to check this, windows apparently doesn't. You could have tried extending the image with zero byte content to the appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

I mounted the image in Windows using `OSFMount` and it worked perfectly. I can access it like a regular drive and I'm pulling files off of it.

To sum up, I had a 500GB drive that I was using to back up files to. It was formatted in NTFS. No other partitions. Read and write speeds were plummeting so I spent a WEEK solid imaging the entire disk using `GNU ddrescue` in Linux. Then I used `OSFMount` to actually mount it in Windows and get files off of it.